# Access Violation in ChangeDisplaySettingsExA()

Tags: windows, graphics, mfc, windbg

While running a code which fakes a display on DVI port and then does `SetDisplayMode` on it, we got an Access Violation, below is the stack trace:

```
0:002> k
  *** Stack trace for last set context - .thread/.cxr resets it
 # ChildEBP RetAddr
00 00a4d5b0 74f42c79 ntdll!memcpy+0x33
01 00a4d5dc 770af94c gdi32!GdiConvertToDevmodeW+0x109
02 00a4d624 737c59e6 user32!ChangeDisplaySettingsExA+0x9c
03 00a4d9f4 737980e0 [...]SetDisplayMode+0x5a6
```

The process is 32-bit and I entered following commands in WinDbg:

```
.symfix
.sympath
.reload
!analyze -v
.excr
k
```

However when I entered `~*kv`, I got all the threads but none of them reported any exception. Currently I am finding it very difficult to find exception record and exception context.

Comment: Did you run `excr`, or `.excr`? The latter is correct.

Comment: Try `~0s;k;~1s;k` and see if any thread has a hash sign (`#`). Try `.exr -1` to see the last exception. And please, don't post pictures like this. You can copy text from WinDbg and edit what you don't want.

Comment: Please cross-check your commands. `symfix` -> `.symfix`, `sympath` -> `.sympath` (if you don't use `.sympath+` this might destroy `.symfix`), `reload`-> `.reload`, `excr` -> `.excr`. It would be very interesting to see the output of those commands. The commands themselves are not very helpful for us. We know them already.

Comment: I am extremely Sorry, all the commands have '.' as a prefix except for !analyze and k, The problem I am facing is once I do !analyze -v and then set the exception context and record using .excr, I can get the stack trace using k command, but from this stack trace I am not able to deduce which thread it belongs to and why ChangeDisplaySettingsExA(..) function threw an exception.